# CSS2 not matching as expected

Tags: css

I have a css rule. its job is to place the left column of my site template in it's correct position.  I'm trying to optimize my css.

```
* html #left { left:220px }
```

I would expect that the below css would work the same...It does not in Chrome or IE9

```
#left {left:220px}
```

However, explicitly defining the whole path as below...works correctly.

```
html body div div #left
```

### Only CSS being used on page. Verified in Chrome inspector.

```
html {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
font-size:80%;
width:100%;
}


.ie7 {
font-size:80%;
width:100%;
}

.ie8 {
font-size:80%;
width:100%;
}

.ie9 {
font-size:80%;
width:100%;
}


body 
{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
font: .95em "Arial","Helvetica","Trebuchet MS","Verdana","Times New Roman","Sans-Serif"; 
min-width:960px;
max-width:960px;
margin: 0px auto auto auto;
padding:0px 10px;
}


        #header
        {
            text-align:left;
        }

        #container {
            padding-left: 220px;      /* LC width */
            padding-right: 30px;     /* RC width */
            overflow: hidden;
            min-height:100%;
            padding-bottom:300px; 
            background-color:White;
        }

        #container .column {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            padding-bottom: 20010px;  /* X + padding-bottom */
            margin-bottom: -20000px;  /* X */           
        }



        #left {
            width: 200px;             /* LC width */
            padding:0 10px;
            right: 260px;             /* LC width */
            margin-left: -100%;


        }

    /*  #right {
            width: 200px;             
            padding:0px 10px;
            margin-right: -290px;               
        }
        */

                #center {
            width: 100%;
            background-color:#fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;         
        }

        #footer-wrapper
        {
            background-color:#fff;
        }

        #footer {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            background-color:#163748; 
            color:white;
            padding:0;
            text-align:center;
            /*border-top:1px solid #9fa8ac;*/
            height:150px; 
            padding-top:10px;                       
        }
        #footer p
        {
            text-align:center;
        }

#footer a
{
    color:White;

}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}


#left 
{
    left:220px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have other styles that could override the `#left { left: 220px; }`? Whats your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS you're trying to optimise is this:

```
* html #left { left:220px }
```

The reason you're having problems with is it because it's actually a CSS hack, designed to work with specific browsers.

In a standards-compliant browser, there are no elements above `html` in the DOM, and therefore `* html` is meaningless and will not select anything.

However in certain versions of IE, this did actually work. Therefore, using `* html` in a selector is a CSS hack for code that you only want to work in those versions of IE.

From memory, this particular hack only worked in IE6, which means that the person who wrote that code was trying to fix a problem in IE6 that didn't appear in other browsers by hacking around it. You'll likely find that there's another line setting the `left` property to something different for other browsers.

Clearly this isn't code that you're going to want to be run in IE9.

If you're lucky, you don't need to support IE6 any more, in which case you can throw this hack away entirely.

If you're unlucky, and you need to continue supporting IE6, then just keep the code as is. It isn't hurting anyone.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, so why does `#left {left:220px;}` not work in IE9?  if you are saying this is a fix for IE6.

Comment: Is there another `left` attribute elsewhere that is overriding it? (as I suggested there may be in the answer) Look in the developer tools CSS inspector to see what styles are being applied. What I can tell you is that all browsers other than IE6 will ignore the `* html` selector, so that `left:220px` won't have been in use before except in IE6.

Comment: I've stripped out all but the above css i've attached to my original question. I'm running chrome and this issue is still apparent.

Comment: okay, looking at the code: so you've verified in the chrome inspector that `left;220px` is being used. however, note that there's also a `right` and `width` attributes being set on the `#left` element elsewhere in the css. if the element has a fixed width, then setting `left` and `right` together is invalid; one must override the other. So probably the original intention was that IE6 used the `left` and everything else used the `right`. Doesn't sound very designed, but that's probably the intention. As I said in the answer, the solution is probably just to drop this selector entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code, my guess is that this is a CSS specificity issue.

Here's a couple of articles on the topic that you might find enlightening:

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thank you! it was a specifity issue!! I had an ID and class defined on the element.